# Nuxt 3 (nuxt generate) change static output directory?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vuejs3, nuxtjs3

Nuxt 2 we were able to specify the output directory:

```
export default {
  target: 'static',

  generate: {
    dir: 'build/_site',
  },
}
```

Now I'm using Nuxt 3 and cannot figure out how to specify the output directory when running generate. Was the generate support removed?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In nuxt3 it can be done by overriding nitro's config in `nuxt.config.ts` like this:

```
const path = require('path');

// https://nuxt.com/docs/api/configuration/nuxt-config
export default defineNuxtConfig({
  ...
  nitro: {
    output: {
      publicDir: path.join(__dirname, 'your path here')
    }
  },
  ...
}
```

You can check [Nitro's documetantion](https://nitro.unjs.io/config/)